# Shaded transparent background in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want transparent tablelayout background with light shaded grey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML layout add this:

```
android:background="#BCB8B8"
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an XML in your drawable folder:

**gray_shade.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#00000000"
      android:centerColor="#30000000"
      android:endColor="#40000000"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

Now, use it in your XML for background of your layout as:

```
...
android:background="@drawable/gray_shade"
...
```

Comment: Thanks for this. A detail: The value for `startColor` is missing a 0